# Exporting Xml data from oracle database in csv file and reading in shell script

Tags: xml, oracle, shell, export-to-csv

I have a requirement to extract XML data in CSV format from the oracle database and then read the data in a shell script.

Here is my query:

```
select routeset_name as  routeset_name,
Trim(Replace(a.XML_MSG.getStringVal(),' ','')) as xml_msg
from ums_lrt_staging_routeset_xml_msg a
```

Here is my shell script

```
while IFS="," read -r ROUTESET_NAME XML_MSG
do
  echo "ROUTESET_NAME: $ROUTESET_NAME"
  echo "XML_MSG: $XML_MSG"
  echo ""
done < <(tail RouteSets.csv)
```

but it is not working as expected. This is how Routeset file contents looks like after export:

```
ROUTESET_NAME,XML_MSG
test,<?xml version="1.0" standalone='yes'?>
<localRoutes>
  <route>
    <user type="string">100</user>
    <next type="regex">100</next>
  </route>
  <emsVersion>
    <version>1</version>
  </emsVersion>
</localRoutes>
```

and this is the output I am getting:

```
ROUTESET_NAME: XML_MSG
XML_MSG:

ROUTESET_NAME: "<pre><?xml version=""1.0"" standalone='yes'?>"
XML_MSG:

ROUTESET_NAME:
XML_MSG:

ROUTESET_NAME:
XML_MSG:

ROUTESET_NAME:
XML_MSG:

ROUTESET_NAME:
XML_MSG:

ROUTESET_NAME:
XML_MSG:
```

My expected should be:

```
ROUTESET_NAME: test
XML_MSG:<?xml version="1.0" standalone='yes'?><localRoutes><route><user type="string">100</user><next type="regex">100</next></route><emsVersion><version>1</version></emsVersion></localRoutes>
```

Here is what I have tried:

- Tried getStringValue method to convert XML to String but didn't work.
- Tried the Trim method thinking leading or trailing spaces might be an
  issue but didn't work.
- Tried Replace method thinking spaces between tags might be the issue
  but didn't work

please help me or guide me where I am going wrong

Comment: *`CSV sample` and `output sample`* -> aren't both of them the same? Btw, better to use a text file rather than image for whom will try to answer the question.

Comment: Please post your actual data, code and output as formatted text, not images. "Didn't work" isn't very helpful - please explain more. Are you stuck on getting the data into a file (which you seem to have done) or just reading it - it isn't clear from your question? Which OS and shell (and version) are you using? Do you really have `< <(tail -n +5 RouteSets.csv)` or have you retyped that? Does your file have more data than you showed - you're skipping the first 5 lines, which you haven't shown, but is there more too?